# Migrating source code from TFS to VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to migrate Source code from TFS to VSTS. I tried git-tf command to migrate and was able to migrate successfully but i am not able to migrate the history. Can someone guide me on what i am doing wrong. Please note i am not migrating to GITVC but migrating to TFVC in Visual studio from On premise TFS server.

Steps are ...

1. git-tf clone http://onprimisetfsurl/ $/project project
2. git-tf clone http://Visualstudiotfvcurl/ $project project1
3. git pull project1 into project
4. git-tf checkin --deep

Comment: What's the version control on your TFS? Git or TFVC?

Comment: So you want to use git-tf to convert the TFS TFVC repository to a local Git repository and then push it to a VSTS TFVC repository?

Comment: Yes that was the plan. Able to successfully push the code but i am losing out on history.

Answer (score 2):

Look at OpsHub https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2 since that is the one that was recommended by the VSTS manager https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2014/05/14/migrating-on-premises-tfs-to-vs-online/
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/adopting-vsts also covers other tools if that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add "--deep" when you perform git-tf clone:

```
git-tf clone http://onprimisetfsurl/ $/project --deep
```

Add my steps for your reference:

1. git-tf clone http://tfsurl $/tfsproject --deep
2. Create a project "vstsproject" in VSTS.
3. Delete the "BuildProcessTemplates" folder in the vstsproject from web portal.
4. Create a new folder for vstsproject on local machine.
5. Run "git init" to set this folder to a git repository.
6. Pull the changes in tfsproject into the new created repo.
7. Run "git log" to make sure the history is correct.
8. git-tf configure https://vstsurl $/vstsproject --deep
9. git-tf checkin --deep

Comment: No luck with that ..one thing i noted was when i do a pull i get the below error fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories so i use --allow-unrelated-histories but i guess that should not have any issues with history

Comment: One more thing i observed is on my local workspace when i do git log it gives me complete histroy but not in VSTS history Tab.

Comment: @Pravin In which repository you run the git-tf checkin command? Project or Project1? Also, you need to pull the project into project1, since project1 is the repository which linked to VSTS repository.

Comment: @Pravin Is the repository on VSTS an new empty repository without any code?

Comment: @Pravin I just followed your steps and can get the same behavior as you. However, if the VSTS project is a new project without any code, delete the "BuildProcessTemplates" folder in it, and use "git-tf configure" instead of "git-tf clone" command for it, the history will be checked in and displayed in VSTS web portal correctly.

Comment: Juts a quick one when you say use git-tf configure instaed of git-tf clone do u mean to say add the remote URL and then pull the code  for both the repos?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120396/discussion-between-eddie-msft-and-pravin).

Comment: Also i have noticed that the history is saved with my username instead of respective committers. I used --metadata flag while checkin but didnt work out. i will try to check any option in git-tf which will move user data as well.

Comment: @Pravin It is expected behavior since all the changesets are checkin by your account.