# Copy Team Project with History in VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub, tfvc, team-project

I'm hoping to copy an existing team project to a new one in order to clean up the content, whilst preserving the history / allowing me to do a dry run of this task before doing it for real, without impacting those currently working on that project.

We're using VSTS (aka VSO) as our version control solution.
I've previously copied projects between TFS and VSTS using the OpsHub migration utility.  I had hoped that I could copy team projects using the same tool, but it appears that this tool is locked to only allow the source to be a self-hosted Team Foundation solution; not VSTS.

Is anyone aware of how team projects can be copied within VSTS?

---

Suggested Duplicate: [Migrating source code from TFS to VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820443/migrating-source-code-from-tfs-to-vsts)

My question differs from the above as that relates to TFS to VSTS, as opposed to VSTS to VSTS as discussed in my question.  The free OpsHub tool takes care of the TFS to VSTS question, but (the free version) doesn't cover the VSTS to VSTS scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating source code from TFS to VSTS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820443/migrating-source-code-from-tfs-to-vsts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to copy team projects and all their associated artifacts. You've already found the OpsHub utility, it has a more expensive bigger brother, the Integration Manager, which is able to do what you need for a significant price per project.

- Product: http://opshub.com/products/opshub-integration-manager/
- Pricing: http://opshub.com/products/pricing-oim/

There are also a few open source solutions available that each fill in part of the gaps, some copy work items, other sources and others test artifacts, but there are few tools that offer a full solution.

The easiest way is to start over and migrate without history, just snapshot your current working set and keep the old data around. If that really isn't an option, prepare for a frustrating or expensive (or both) period ahead.

Answer (score 1):

The commercial version of OpsHub Migration Utility also allows copying of VSTS projects from one account to another.

- Product: http://opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/
- Pricing: http://opshub.com/products/pricing-ovsmu/