# Is it possible to migrate only source and code history from Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Service?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-migration

We are trying to migrate from TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps Service. We apparently have partial configurations of Work Item and Process Templates that will not pass TFSMigrator validation, and I'm searching for a way to skip all of that completely and *only* migrate source control and version history.

I've gone through multiple iterations on a development server and have a successful process down to upgrade from TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps Server 2019. Unfortunately the Migrator.exe tool still continues to fail, and as much as I've read up on the XML modifications that would be necessary, and we might be able to do to reapply and reconfigure the Work Items and Process Templates, I'm having difficulty getting the final pieces in place. It's all the more frustrating because we never actually used Work Items, Build Tools, Test Plans, etc. All we are interested in moving is our primary TFVC project's source code with version history, and for now I'd be entirely happy to use the new "Basic" Work Item process in the Azure DevOps Service.

Here are some of the problems we're seeing in the DataMigrationTool.log if someone has other ideas, but I'm mostly interested in skipping the need to fix all of this entirely...

```
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: TF402571: Required element FeedbackRequestWorkItems is missing from Process Configuration.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: TF402571: Required element FeedbackResponseWorkItems is missing from Process Configuration.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: TF402574: ProcessConfiguration doesn't specify required TypeField Team.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: TF402574: ProcessConfiguration doesn't specify required TypeField RemainingWork.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: TF402574: ProcessConfiguration doesn't specify required TypeField Order.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: TF402574: ProcessConfiguration doesn't specify required TypeField Effort.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: TF402574: ProcessConfiguration doesn't specify required TypeField Activity.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: TF402574: ProcessConfiguration doesn't specify required TypeField ApplicationStartInformation.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: TF402574: ProcessConfiguration doesn't specify required TypeField ApplicationLaunchInstructions.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: TF402574: ProcessConfiguration doesn't specify required TypeField ApplicationType.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Feature.xml:: TF26177: The field System.IterationId cannot be renamed from 'IterationID' to 'Iteration ID'. 
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\SharedParameter.xml:: TF26177: The field System.IterationId cannot be renamed from 'IterationID' to 'Iteration ID'. 
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: The following element contains an error: TypeFields. TF400526: Element is missing. The XML is not valid.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: The following element contains an error: RequirementBacklog. TF401107: The attribute 'category' is missing from the element.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: The following element contains an error: RequirementBacklog. TF401107: The attribute 'pluralName' is missing from the element.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: The following element contains an error: RequirementBacklog/States. TF400526: Element is missing. The XML is not valid.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: The following element contains an error: RequirementBacklog/Columns. TF400508: No columns are defined. You must define at least one column.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: The following element contains an error: RequirementBacklog/AddPanel. TF400526: Element is missing. The XML is not valid.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: The following element contains an error: TaskBacklog. TF401107: The attribute 'category' is missing from the element.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: The following element contains an error: TaskBacklog/States. TF400526: Element is missing. The XML is not valid.
[Error  @14:22:24.568] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: The following element contains an error: TaskBacklog/Columns. TF400508: No columns are defined. You must define at least one column.
```

Edit: Thanks to Daniel Mann's comments and after reviewing some of the other options around git-tf (which does seem to have stopped development btw, for anyone else searching) it looks like fixing the process templates and work item issues will be the only workable solution for us because we need to try to retain user check-in history as well. It seems that an improved solution here would be if Microsoft could extend the TFSMigration/Migrator programs to allow users to do a "Repo Only" code and version migration and bypass work item and process template historical data. I'll try to share my experiences working through the Migrator logs if I'm able to get it working (and explain it coherently!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating source code from TFS to VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820443/migrating-source-code-from-tfs-to-vsts)

Comment: Very much appreciate the link to the existing article Daniel, but I don't know that I'd call it a duplicate because other users may not be familiar with the TFS to VSTS nomenclature now that everything is "Azure DevOps". It also looks like using the git-tf commands will lose the named check-in user per Eddie Chen? If I can find a way to make that work and keep the check-in user that would be preferable. I'll also take a look at some of the other links there next week - thanks again!

Comment: Your best bet is to fix the process template problems and use the official migration tool. Anything else is going to lose some degree of fidelity. With regard to the process template problems, did you use the post-upgrade process template upgrade tool? If you're using stock process templates, that should update everything and fix all of those issues.

Comment: I keep avoiding that as the only real solution, but I think you're right. :)  I believe I tried using the process template upgrade tool, and repeatedly tried the "Configure features" tool but it keeps telling me, "There are no process templates available with valid configuration settings for this team project. Your team project cannot be configured automatically." There's a lot of ole cruft in there that unfortunately I wasn't around for so I'm taking it apart as I can. I'll take another look at the upgrade tool though in case I missed something.

Comment: @jefmes Were u able to fix them? How?